# nods js mvc framework to work with react js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, model-view-controller

I am developing a new application and have decided to use node.js for back end and MongoDB as data storage and ReactJS for front end. I will be using MVC architecture pattern and there will be REST APIs which will be consumed by 3rd parties mainly to integrate with this new aplication.

I am looking for node.js MVC framework which will help build the application and possibly APIs also. I need suggestions on which MVC framework to use. Do I need seperate framework for API since those will be hosted seperately and will not share application codebase.

Looking forward to hear back from the community.

Comment: if your API is mainly crud operations take a look at loopback from IBM

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. any idea on the mvc framework that goes well with MongoDB and ReactJS

Comment: I looked at frameworks like Express, Koa, Sail & Meteor but not sure which one to go ahead with.
As I have mentioned before, my application will connect to MongoDB as data storage. There will be views depending on roles and we have plans to use ReactJS as frontend.
REST API's needs to be created which will be used by the application as well as 3rd party applictions.
I really need suggestions on this. I found Express is most widely used but Sail supports MVC & ORM while KOA has ES6 generator instead of callbacks. Meteor has data synchronization and support for mobile as well.